# Asp.net website first start is very slow

Tags: asp.net

The first time I load the website in the production web server, it start very slow, subsequent pages load very quickly (included the home page).

I precompiled the site, but nothing changes.

I don't have any code at Application start.
I don't have cached items.

Any ideas? How can I find out what is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just your app domain loading up and loading any binaries into memory. Also, it's initializing static variables, so if you have a static variable that loads up a lot of data from the db, it might take a bit.

Comment: Surely it's a design flaw when starting a web site is that slow?

Answer (score 2):

When you published the site, did you choose to make the website "updatable" in the publish website's settings or not? If I remember well, the aspx / ascx file need to be compiled as well, and if they are "updatable" then the first start will cause a recompile of those resources.

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned on [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we.aspx) in your web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your event log?

Answer (score 1):

use http://www.iis.net/expand/ApplicationWarmUp for warming up your app
this is for IIS 7.5 - so if you are running on Server R2 then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you publish your application in 'release' and not 'debug'. I've noticed this decreases loading time considerably. The web.config file will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like background compiling; though if you're precompiling, that shouldn't be an issue.

First thing I would look at is your ORM (if any). NHibernate, in particular, has a serious startup penalty, as it runs multiple compilers in the background at startup to turn each class in your data layer into its own in-memory assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick nod at Darren. That's typical behavior of a .NET app after a DLL update is made. After the initial load everything should zip along just fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "precompile" the site, are you using the [aspnet_compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28VS.80%29.aspx) utility to precompile, or simply using the "Build site" option in Visual Studio?

If you are not carrying out the former, I recommend [giving it a spin](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/10/17/8190.aspx). Coupled with [Web Deployment Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336619.aspx), you should have an easier time deploying your site for each release.

Answer (score 0):

The initial slowness is a couple things:

- The appDomain is being setup
- ASP.NET is parsing and compiling the ASPX pages.
- Global Contexts are being initialized.

This is normal behavior for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

> @Mickey: No, it is turned off. Do I need to turn it on to find out?

The trace log will show you how long each action takes.  It could help you find what is taking so long.

[Here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/07/17/2396.aspx) is a link that might help you get it setup.