# ASP.NET brutally slow to bring up..even after site has been visited

Tags: asp.net

Got a weird one here. Site is deployed into production and trying to bring the site up takes for ever even after the site has been visited within the last minute or so. Once on the site it is fast but for whatever reason the intial request drags on. Im using forms auth on IIS 6 / Win2003R2.

Here is the trace output but not sure if this is fast or not:

```
Trace Information 
Category Message From First(s) From Last(s) 
aspx.page Begin PreInit   
aspx.page End PreInit 0.000724673107894998 0.000725 
aspx.page Begin Init 0.00076126993793904 0.000037 
aspx.page End Init 0.000788368354078521 0.000027 
aspx.page Begin InitComplete 0.000803454070279882 0.000015 
aspx.page End InitComplete 0.000818819151596083 0.000015 
aspx.page Begin PreLoad 0.000838095344520044 0.000019 
aspx.page End PreLoad 0.000853181060721405 0.000015 
aspx.page Begin Load 0.000867987411807925 0.000015 
aspx.page End Load 0.000924698530120448 0.000057 
aspx.page Begin LoadComplete 0.000944254088159249 0.000020 
aspx.page End LoadComplete 0.00096045726481997 0.000016 
aspx.page Begin PreRender 0.000975263615906491 0.000015 
aspx.page End PreRender 0.00109343505948382 0.000118 
aspx.page Begin PreRenderComplete 0.00111103506171874 0.000018 
aspx.page End PreRenderComplete 0.00112640014303494 0.000015 
aspx.page Begin SaveState 0.00208294629624715 0.000957 
aspx.page End SaveState 0.00985628061667056 0.007773 
aspx.page Begin SaveStateComplete 0.00989231871648492 0.000036 
aspx.page End SaveStateComplete 0.00990796316291596 0.000016 
aspx.page Begin Render 0.00992276951400248 0.000015 
aspx.page End Render 0.0115989602030426 0.001676
```

This application resides in a VPN so no outside access. What can i do to check if its a network issue so I can contact the Network people?

Code in Global.asax

```
/// <summary>
        /// Fires when the application is started
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires when the session is started
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: What does "forever" mean? 2 seconds? 4 seconds? 1 minute?

Comment: What's in Application_Start and Session_Start?  Have you checked the system and application event logs on the server to see if your app pools are healthy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be appdomain startup [Asp.net website first start is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260/asp-net-website-first-start-is-very-slow)

Could be ASP dynamic compile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

Could be code signing validation http://rusanu.com/2009/07/24/fix-slow-application-startup-due-to-code-sign-validation/

There are also other similar patterns (DB warm up, connection pool warm up etc).

Comment: This sysmptom doesnt happen on my webserver hosted outside the VPN. Site pops right up. Same code base of course.

Comment: Could be the code signing CRL check (second link). That manifests onyl on machines w/o access to the CRL authority.

Comment: Make that **3rd** link, not 2nd

Comment: I checked the registry but coudnt find an entry for: 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CertDllCreateCertificateChainEngine\'

Comment: Can that VPN box open the url http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/CSPCA.crl
 ? If yes, then code signing is unlikely the issue. If no, the it worth adding the registry keys as per the MSDN article linked in my blog.

Comment: I was able to hit the URL provided from the box in question.

Comment: Does your project use SQL Express user instances? (do you have AttachDBFilename in your connection string)

Comment: No attachdbfilename. Called the helpdesk and they mentioned a fiber optic cable being cut as a possible reason. I dont think thats it. That would affect performace for the whole site..

Comment: For the record, did you guys figured out the issue?

Comment: Nope...looks like an issue with a Proxy Server and not the website at all. For whatever reason the bypass code in the .PAC file for the proxy server isn't getting processed so it hangs for a while before bringing the site up.