# Check Active Directory Role taking too long

Tags: c#, active-directory

i have this code to check for group membership but it seems to be taking too long to respond and slowing down my app, it takes almost 7-12 sec to respond, i just need to check for one particular group membership, is there a faster way to do this?

```
  public static bool isInRole(UserAccount userAccount, string groupName)
        {


            using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, userAccount.DomainName))
            {
                using (var grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, groupName))
                {
                    bool isInRole = grp != null &&
                        grp
                        .GetMembers(true)
                        .Any(m => m.SamAccountName == userAccount.UserName);
                    return isInRole;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Can you cache the response for an acceptable amount of time?

Comment: how can i do so? i am using WCF service .net 4.0

Comment: Does the group have lots of members? If so, you might get a quicker response by finding if the user account's groups contain the group you are looking for, instead of finding if the group's members contain the account you are looking for.

Comment: @adrianbanks how can i do that

Comment: It's been a while since I did this myself and don't have VS to hand - Does the userAccount object have a `Groups` property / `GetGroups()` function?

Comment: USerAccount is a Custom class that i created

Comment: In that case, let me rephrase - when you retrieve the current user from AD, does the object you get have additional properties you can query to get the groups?

Comment: i have username and pwd as string, i do not have princiap obejcts so no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your specific AD at hand to test this - but it might be worth an attempt: instead of checking the group's members for a particular users (there could potentially be thousands of members), why don't you check the user's group membership to see if the user has the right group??

Something like :

```
public static bool isInRole(UserAccount userAccount, string groupName)
{
   using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, userAccount.DomainName))
   using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userAccount.UserName))
   {
      bool isInRole = user != null &&
                      user.GetAuthorizationGroups()
                      .Any(g => g.Name == groupName);
      return isInRole;
   }
}
```

Maybe that way around things will be a bit faster?

Comment: what is grp, when i build i get grp doesn;t exits in current conetxt

Comment: @marc_s - would you mind checking this out. this is really strange along the same lines and I can't get an expert's eyes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147132/active-directory-group-membership-checking-in-net-4-5

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you an answer as we don't have enough information but to track down your problem...

Firstly, try querying AD using the standard tools (run on the web server) - is this just as slow? If so, it's likely a network/DC issue.

Assuming it's just your implementation that's slow...

Are you calling a WCF service hosted in a website that's [taking time to compile/load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260/asp-net-website-first-start-is-very-slow)? To test this, do multiple calls and compare delays - If the first is significantly longer, have a look at your IIS settings 0 You can increase idle time before app pool unload, etc. to mitigate the problem.

If You're certain it's that your code taking too long, use the [Visual Studio Pofiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) which will identify which functions/calls are causing the delay - If it's in your code, optimise it, If it's in the framework then you're either using it wrong or you've found a problem with the framework (unlikely).

If you can edit your question to include answers to the above, we may be able to help further

**Edit:** In response to the question about caching within WCF there are a number of ways to approach this - You can replace the Persistence provider for the service class to make it a singleton - then you can just use private variables/memory for caching. This requires your class to be thread-safe.

Alternatives include: database, file system, app-wide in-memory cache ([System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx))

Comment: i have used the VS profileer and found that this particular section is taking too long.

Comment: Which line in particular, the loop, the linq or the `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, groupName)` ? or a split of the 3? Have you enabled .Net Framework debugging (under Tools-Options-Debugging) this allows you to step into the framework itself - enable this, turn on automatic download of debug symbols so you can see readable code not disassembly then re-profile. This should show you specifically which calls are causing issues - I suspect it's in network code but could be anything (maybe it's trying to cache but the cache is timing out, etc.)

Comment: caching in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443%28VS.100%29.aspx is limited to service operation olnly

Comment: @Natasha I may have misunderstood your point but you can either use the caching framework in the WCF service to cache responses or in the client to cache the results of the WCF call - so it should work at either end. This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997362.aspx is a WPF caching example but could be applied to other .Net frameworks - As I said, I may have misunderstood your point in which case, please clarify :)